# Shopware NPM Packages in Administration

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm having trouble using an NPM package in the Shopware Administration.I'm trying to use Chart.js, and it's not working. I followed the instructions from the [Shopware documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/using-npm-dependencies) with the missionlog package, but I'm getting the following error:

```
    ERROR in /var/www/html/custom/plugins/ShopwareWidgets/src/Resources/app/administration/node_modules/vue-chartjs/dist/index.js 198:37
    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (198:37)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
    |             const ref = shallowRef(null);
    |             const reforwardRef = (chartRef)=>{
    >                 ref.value = chartRef?.chart;
    |             };
    |             expose({
    
    ERROR in /var/www/html/custom/plugins/ShopwareWidgets/src/Resources/app/administration/node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js 567:17
    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (567:17)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
    |     };
    | class DatasetController {
    >  static defaults = {};
    |  static datasetElementType = null;
    |  static dataElementType = null;
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! administration@1.0.0 build: `mode=production webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the administration@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/www/.npm/_logs/2023-07-11T09_21_34_527Z-debug.log
```

Here is the log file with additional information:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/var/www/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/var/www/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.16
3 info using node@v12.22.12
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle administration@1.0.0~prebuild: administration@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle administration@1.0.0~build: administration@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle administration@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle administration@1.0.0~build: PATH: /var/www/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/html/vendor/shopware/administration/Resources/app/administration/node_mod$
9 verbose lifecycle administration@1.0.0~build: CWD: /var/www/html/vendor/shopware/administration/Resources/app/administration
10 silly lifecycle administration@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'mode=production webpack' ]
11 silly lifecycle administration@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle administration@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: administration@1.0.0 build: `mode=production webpack`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/var/www/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/www/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1022:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
14 verbose pkgid administration@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /var/www/html/vendor/shopware/administration/Resources/app/administration
16 verbose Linux 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
17 verbose argv "/var/www/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/bin/node" "/var/www/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v12.22.12
19 verbose npm  v6.14.16
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error administration@1.0.0 build: `mode=production webpack`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the administration@1.0.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

My `webpack.config.js` file is as follows:

```js
const { join, resolve } = require('path');

module.exports = () => {
    return {
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                '@chartjs': resolve(
                    join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'chart.js')
                ),
                '@chartjsvue': resolve(
                    join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'vue-chartjs', 'dist')
                )
            }
        }
    };
}
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
src
|- Resources
   |- app
      |- administration
         |- build
            |- webpack.config.js
         |- node_modules
         |- src
         |- package-lock.json
         |- package.json
```

Could someone please help me figure out why I'm getting this error and how to resolve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have to configure the `babel-loader` manually. I'm not sure if this was always the case, as it is already configured in the "main" `webpack.config.js` of the administration and in theory the custom config should get merged into that.

Modifying your `webpack.config.js` like this should work though:

```js
const { join, resolve } = require('path');

module.exports = () => {
    return {
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                '@chartjs': resolve(
                    join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'chart.js')
                ),
                '@chartjsvue': resolve(
                    join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'vue-chartjs', 'dist')
                )
            }
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        compact: true,
                        cacheDirectory: true,
                        presets: [
                            '@babel/preset-env'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Hey @dneustadt is it even possible to render jsx files inside of shopware 6 with babel I am trying all day long with no luck I will appreciate it if you have any Information that could help me :)